# Xamarin form: Is there a way to get a thumbnail from the video

Tags: xamarin, media, snapshot

I am using a MediaPlugin which can pick up photo/video. I need to display their thumbnail. Is there a way to extract the thumbnail through video file.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/tree/master/src